# C++20 Wrapper class for an unsigned integer type and a templated derived class that codes modular arithmetic type

Tags: c++, integer, inheritance, c++20, wrapper

The context is a library to represent numbers (in this case integers) by wheighted position by radix powers for every radix R, passed as template argument. These derived types are digits of radix R, **R_alphabet = {0,1,2,...,R-1}**. The base class is to have holded the dig_t object as base_dig_t plus the radiz in the container for the number.

```
template<std::unsigned_integral Type>
struct base_dig_t;

template<   std::unsigned_integral Type,
            Type R
        >
// It does not add any data member to class
struct dig_t : public base_dig_t<Type>; 

template<std::unsigned_integral Type>
struct base_dig_t
{
    // default constructor
    constexpr 
    base_dig_t() 
    noexcept : 
        m_d(0) 
    {}
    
    // constructor by constant reference to 
    // wrapped arithmetic integral type
    constexpr 
    base_dig_t(const Type& t) 
    noexcept : 
        m_d(t) 
    {}
    // constructor by move the 
    // wrapped arithmetic integral type
    constexpr 
    base_dig_t(Type&& t) 
    noexcept : 
        m_d(std::move(t)) 
    {}
    
    // constructor by constant reference 
    // to derived type
    template<Type R>
    constexpr 
    base_dig_t(const dig_t<Type,R>& t) 
    noexcept : 
        m_d(t.base_dig_t::m_d) 
    {}
    // constructor by move the derived type
    template<Type R>
    constexpr 
    base_dig_t(dig_t<Type,R>&& t) 
    noexcept : 
        m_d(std::move(t.base_dig_t::m_d)) 
    {}
    
    // usual constructor by reference
    constexpr 
    base_dig_t(const base_dig_t&) 
    noexcept = default;
    // usual constructor by move
    constexpr 
    base_dig_t(const base_dig_t&&) 
    noexcept = default;
    
    // assignation operator by constant reference 
    // to wrapped arithmetic integral type
    constexpr 
    const base_dig_t & 
    operator= (const Type& t) 
    noexcept 
    {m_d = t; 
     return (*this);}
    // assignation operator by reference 
    // to wrapped arithmetic integral type
    constexpr 
    base_dig_t & 
    operator= (Type& t) 
    noexcept 
    {m_d = t; 
     return (*this);}
    // assignation operator by move 
    // wrapped arithmetic integral type
    constexpr 
    base_dig_t & 
    operator= (Type&& t) 
    noexcept     
    {m_d = std::move(t); 
     return (*this);}

    // assignation operator by constant reference 
    // to derived type
    template<Type R>
    constexpr 
    const base_dig_t & 
    operator= (const dig_t<Type,R>& t) 
    noexcept  
    {m_d = t.base_dig_t::m_d; 
     return (*this);}
    // assignation operator by reference to derived type
    template<Type R>
    constexpr 
    base_dig_t & 
    operator =(dig_t<Type,R>& t) 
    noexcept  
    {m_d = t.base_dig_t::m_d; 
     return (*this);}
    // assignation operator by move the derived type
    template<Type R>
    constexpr 
    base_dig_t & 
    operator =(dig_t<Type,R>&& t) 
    noexcept 
    {m_d = std::move(t.base_dig_t::m_d); 
     return (*this);}

    
    // usual assignation operator by constant reference
    constexpr 
    const base_dig_t & 
    operator= (const base_dig_t& d) 
    noexcept  
    {m_d = d.m_d; 
     return (*this);}
    // usual assignation operator by reference
    constexpr 
    base_dig_t & 
    operator=(base_dig_t&) 
    noexcept = default; 
    // usual assignation operator by move
    constexpr 
    base_dig_t & 
    operator= (base_dig_t&&) 
    noexcept = default;
    
    // several casts
    constexpr explicit 
    operator Type() const 
    noexcept
    {return m_d;}
    constexpr explicit 
    operator const Type&() const 
    noexcept 
    {return m_d;}
    constexpr explicit 
    operator Type&() 
    noexcept 
    {return m_d;}
    constexpr explicit 
    operator Type&&() 
    noexcept 
    {return std::move(m_d);}
    
protected:

    Type m_d;
    
};

// This template typename does not add 
// any data member to base class
template<   std::unsigned_integral Type,
            Type R
        >
struct dig_t : public base_dig_t<Type> 
{
    // Contructors from base_dig_t<Type>
    // Assignation operators for base_dig_t<Type>
    // this->base_dig_t::m_d = arg.base_dig_t::m_d%R;
    
    // Contructors from Type
    // Assignation operators for Type
    // this->base_dig_t::m_d = arg%R;

    // Proper constructors
    // Proper assignation operators
    
    // Explicit overload cast operators 
    // to return base_dig_t::m_d
    
    // Overload 
    // by template members functions
    // the arithmetic operators for
    // R-modular behavior   
    
};
```

Comment: To put your description in simpler terms, it's a [bignum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library - is that correct?

Comment: But the library I code is with pedagogical target. One example is bignum, but numbers complement Radix format with fixed width and fixed radix. Or generalized IEEE-754.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I like the style:

```
// several casts
constexpr explicit 
operator Type() const 
noexcept
{return m_d;}
constexpr explicit 
operator const Type&() const 
noexcept 
{return m_d;}
constexpr explicit 
operator Type&() 
noexcept 
{return m_d;}
constexpr explicit 
operator Type&&() 
noexcept 
{return std::move(m_d);}
```

Even one by itself:

```
constexpr explicit 
operator Type() const 
noexcept
{return m_d;}
```

Is hard to read and takes up a lot of vertical space. When you have a bunch it is unreadable:

I would align them like this so it becomes easy to see what changes between them.

```
// several casts
constexpr explicit operator       Type()   const noexcept  {return m_d;}
constexpr explicit operator const Type&()  const noexcept  {return m_d;}
constexpr explicit operator       Type&()        noexcept  {return m_d;}
constexpr explicit operator       Type&&()       noexcept  {return std::move(m_d);}
```

So now that I can read it.
You have a type that automatically converts itself to an R-Value reference. I am not sure if that is allowed or not; but it definitely makes my spidey senses go all funny. Would love to understand the use case of this.